# How can I workaround or fix a printer offset x0y?

Tags: pdf, cups, printer

OK, so I have an old office reject printer, the OKI B4350.
Works great with CUPS and Evince except for one thing: often it prints the page all messed up: offset from the upper left corner and truncated in the lower right corner, and the word x0y or xOy added.

So far, this has never ever happened on the first page I print, but it happens often later in a multi-page print job.
My wild hypothesis is that it's when a preceding page goes to close to (or out in) the margins.
So ideally I'd like to figure out what's wrong, and fix it, and be able to print really tight margins. But if that's not possible, maybe some sort of filter I could put things through to make it happy? pdfcrop hasn't been enough.